# Wordpress import xml feed

Tags: xml, wordpress, import

I can import and RSS feed in Wordpress with something like this.

```
        <ul><?php if(function_exists('fetch_feed')) {
            include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');                        // Includes the necessary files
            $feed = fetch_feed('http://computingondemand.com/news/?feed=rss');  // URL to the feed you want to show
            $limit = $feed->get_item_quantity(10);                              // How many items you wish to display
            $items = $feed->get_items(0, $limit);                               // 0 is start and limit is noted above
        }
        if ($limit == 0) echo '<div>The feed is either empty or unavailable.</div>';
        else foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
        <li>
        <div>
            <a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y @ g:i a'); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <?php echo substr($item->get_description(), 0, 400); ?>
            <p><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>">[Read More...]</a></p>
        </div>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?><ul>
```

Is it possible to do the same sort of thing with an xml feed.

I have a feed that produces stock figures like this.

```
        <stockquotes>
        <Ric>NXT.L</Ric>
        <Currency>GBX</Currency>
        <CurrentPrice>7,420.00</CurrentPrice>
        <Change>-90.00</Change>
        <Time>4:35 PM</Time>
        <High>7,560.00</High>
        <Low>7,415.00</Low>
        <Open>7,530.00</Open>
        <Close>7,420.00</Close>
        <Bid>7,400.00</Bid>
        <Ask>7,565.00</Ask>
        <Volume>236,611</Volume>
        <MarketCapitalMillion>1,134,321.79</MarketCapitalMillion>
        <MarketCapitalBillion>1,134.32</MarketCapitalBillion>
        <arrow>down</arrow>
        </stockquotes>
```

I'd like to import this feed into Wordpress and pull out the content from the xml

I have found one plugin that looks like it could do it but it cost +$100 whihc is a good price but we don't have the finance for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin, it might work for your needs:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/